# SVD of finite field matrix

Tags: python, numpy, finite-field

The galois git hub shows how to compute inverse of finite field matrix. How do compute SVD of non-square finite field matrix?

np.linalg.svd doesn't work. That;'s because matrices (U,S,Vh) have non-integer values. But the type shows as order=2^3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.